# Magento 2.4.3 - Advanced Pricing not changing date

Tags: product, magento2.4.3, advanced-pricing

We have some issues with advanced pricing on products. For Example, products we priced with advanced pricing in June, now can not be changed I.E when new values are being typed in and saved, the previous price remains.

Products that have not been configured with advanced pricing previously do not have this issue.

It appears that some products that have this issue, have been imported by a 3rd party module. I  have raised this issue with the 3rd party and they advised that their module should not overwrite any manual work, such as changing the dates on advanced pricing.

Does anyone have an idea what can cause this issue and how to fix it? The exception log is clear, can't find any error regarding this.

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

Found out what the issue was, one of our profiles had corrupted the DB table and when we tried and change the date it was overwritten by the old value over and over again.

The reason the profile corrupted the DB was due to one of our attributes for a special price. The profile changed the price for store view while the attribute was for global. We changed the attribute to store view after we cleared the old values in the DB.